# Why do Nino and Miku need to fight for the TV?

Tags: culture, the-quintessential-quintuplets

At about 3:20 in the 2nd episode of *5-toubun no Hanayome ∬*, Nino and Miku are fighting over the TV.

[image]

Do parents in Japan forbid their children from having computers or tablets?

If not, Nino and Miku could just watch their favorite shows in their computers or tablets and there would be no need to argue. But in the 1st episode of Season 1, when Uesugi entered the quintuplets' room, there seems to be no computer in their rooms.

If so, why do the parents do that? Do they think having electronic gadgets would have negative influence on children's study (, which might be consistent with [Japanese schools' strict rules](https://lifebuzz.com/japanese-school))? However, having the internet is a great convenience while studying and can save you much pain when you fail to solve some difficult problems. As a doctor who works in a hospital, the quints' father must have a high degree. It would be unbelievable if he is unaware of that.

So, in the end, why do Nino and Miku need to fight for the TV?

Answer (score 5):

Even in late 2010s/early 2020s, people still use television sets.

It's not necessarily about cable or whatever, but a TV has a bigger screen. It's even better than a laptop/desktop computer.

In your screenshot the remote is blocking the way.

[image]

We can see how huge it is in a later screen.

[image]

---

Re computers:

They have. Or at least Miku does. See S01E02:

[image]

Since the game was borrowed from Yotsuba (see below), Yotsuba must have too. I mean, we haven't really examined their rooms in detail have we? Just because you don't see a computer doesn't mean there isn't one.

[image]

Actually you can see the same computer Miku has in S01E01

[image]

Comment: An interesting point, but they still don't have computers or laptops.

Comment: How do you know Gasai? Maybe you/we just haven't seen? (or maybe it's in the manga?) Miku in particular...maybe S01E03 re gaming has a desktop/laptop computer? @Michael

Comment: Who's Gasai? Besides, Miku didn't play games in that ep.

Comment: Gasai is the last name of [yuno gasai](https://futurediary.fandom.com/wiki/Yuno_Gasai). i like to add the word 'gasai' after saying 'you know' in real life because 'you know' sounds like 'yuno'. oh it's s01e02 not s01e03. i'll edit

Answer (score 2):

I think BCLC's answer is one factor. People usually prefer larger screens.

Another thing is rather simple. You can't watch TV on tablets or PC in Japan, without additional device (which is not so commonly used). So whether or not they have those gadgets may not be that relevant.

Nowadays high school kids should have smartphones at least. Due to the covid-19 and tele-education, I think there are many tablet distributed among students, so it is not unusual that they have those gadgets.

Comment: What do you mean by 'additional device'? Do you mean they need to pay for extra TV service, such as VIP or something?

Comment: @Michael What is called 'tuner', like [these](https://moov.ooo/article/5d7603d794431d1a121e36bc). I don't really watch TV and don't know the details... Also, younger people don't watch TV nowadays (e.g. [this](https://www.yomiuri.co.jp/culture/20210520-OYT1T50222/) says about half of 10-29 year olds don't watch TV more than 15 mins on weekdays.)

Comment: @sundowner when you say you don't watch TV, you're really true to your description 'A manga fan' like you don't really watch anime but you read manga?

Comment: @BCLC Right. I've never really been an anime watcher though I used to be an avid manga reader.